# How to return Scala `Unit` type in java function

Tags: scala, java-8

I've a twitter future and I want to implement `onFailure` callback for this.

The type signature for `onFailure` is `def onFailure(fn: Throwable => Unit): Future[A]`.

Below is the sample code from my project:

```
import com.twitter.util.Future

Future f = getTwitterFuture()
f.onFailure(ex -> {
  //business Logic here 
  return; //Not sure how to return scala unit from java
});
```

In the above code if I do `return;`, I get error `Missing return Value`.
If I do `return void`, I get `; expected` error.

I've below scala and java SDK in my project.

Scala version - 2.12.6
Java version - java version "1.8.0_144"

I know scala 2.12.6 binary interoperability works well in java 8. But I don't know how to write this.

Comment: The title of this question doesn't at all reflect the question itself. Care to improve it?

Comment: updated the title. does it look good?

Comment: Much better. :) A good title will draw the right people to help, and makes the question for others who have this issue in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That would be

```
return scala.runtime.BoxedUnit.UNIT;
```